# Display well formatted JSON on SharePoint online

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How to display well formatted json on SharePoint Online? The code snippet webpart does not have JSON option. Are there any available plugins that can be added to SharePoint to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do would be to parse it and "pretty print" it when you `stringify` it. It's not clear what your json looks like, where it's coming from so here's a basic example

```js
const json = { one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, nested: { child: 1}};

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));
```

Comment: We have really long Jsons to show on our SharePoint documentation. The Code Snippet webpart does not have `Json` as an option show that we can collapse the nodes to view it properly. I am currently using monospaced text to show the json, but it is not readable since they have 1000 lines of json showing.